# How do I conditionally include element in array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, ternary-operator

I am wondering how I can conditionally either have an array element or not at all using the following style. I realise in a general sense to do this would be  trivial...
So What I would really like is to be able to not have a particular element at all based on some condition, so far I can make it one value or another.

The actual motivation behind my question is to conditionally show or not show an `[ActionColumn][1]` in `Yii2`. But am more curious in a general sense now.

Thanks!

```
<?php
$middle_name = "James";
$full_name = [
    'Robert',
    (!empty($middle_name)) ? $middle_name : 'NA',
    'Fischer',
];
?>
```

Comment: Can't do it with this syntax. Place a `if` after that will include this information if a condition is met, or modify `$middle_name` to `'NA'` beforehand.

Comment: @Havenard Thanks for the feedback, I wondered if that was the case. Do you see it as a language limitation, or as something you should not be trying to do in that manner?

Comment: @johnsnails, write a function or a class

Comment: It's not a language limitation, it's just semantics. If you are telling PHP to insert 3 elements in the array, all 3 elements will exist in the array even if a condition defines one as `null`. The inline condition has to return something, it cannot result as void. You can instead make a condition to define the array as 2 or 3 elements depending on the content of `$middle_name`, or you can simply insert `$middle_name` there and then use `array_filter()` to remove empty elements from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $middle_name = "James";
    $full_name[] = 'Robert';

    if ($middle_name == '' || $middle_name == null) {
        $full_name[] = 'NA';
    } else {
        $full_name[] = $middle_name;
    }

    $full_name[] = 'Fischer';
?>
```

Comment: Was aware of this type of approach, but it is not entirely suitable the way I am actually setting elements as it is an array inside another array. But aware of the general approach you are referring too.

Comment: Could you add this to your question, then I can help with it